# Select particular record from another table based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables; its structure is given below

[image]

[image]

In the first table I am assigning menu rights based on **RoleID**. In some cases I want to override some additional rights to a particular **user (UserID)**. So this second table is using for additional rights for a particular user.
In this below example; RoleID=2 and MenuID=4 has no Add rights; So i have added 1 rows in second table. While fetching records I need to get that record from second table instead of third row from the first table. How make a query for this purpose?

Comment: Can you include sample data as well formatted text instead of images? Can you also show us the expected result of the query?

Comment: you should add the query you have done untill now, too

Comment: so you want all records from `role_menu_rights` except those `roleid` which has an entry in `user_role_menu_rights`. For that you want the record (userid,roleid) combination from `user_role_menu_rights` ? Give your expected output clearly

Comment: @Utsav exactly correct..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question clearly, this is what you need.

```
select r.application,r.roleid,r.menuid
case when u.roleid is null and u.menuid is null 
   then r.isadd else u.isadd end 
,case when u.roleid is null and u.menuid is null 
  then r.isedit else u.isedit end
-- same case conditions for other columns.

 from role_menu_rights r
left join 
user_role_menu_rights u
on r.roleid=u.roleid
and r.menuid=u.menuid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select u1.Application,u1.UserID, u1.RoleID, u1.MenuID, u1.isAdd, u1.isEdit, u1.isDelete, u1.IsView 
from User_Role_Menu_Right u1 
where u1.UserID = :userID 
union
Select r.Application,u.UserID, r.RoleID, r.MenuID, r.isAdd, r.isEdit, isDelete, IsView 
from User_Role_Menu_Right u, Role_Menu_Right r 
where 
u.UserId = :userId and u.RoleId != r.RoleID and u.MenuID != r.MenuID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use union:

```
select * 
from role_menu_rights 
where not exists 
      (select * 
        from user_role_menu_rights 
         where RoleID = role_menu_rights.RoleID  AND MenuID = role_menu_rights.MenuID )
union all 

select Application, RoleID, MenuID, IsAdd, IsEdit, IsEdit, IsDelete, IsView 
from user_role_menu_rights
```